# Angular JS routing issue when using Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have a situation, I want to redirect user to next page if login is successful. 
Else it should stay on login page.

Here is my code where I have set the routing and routeChangeStart listener.

```
function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap", "easypiechart", "mgo-angular-wizard", "textAngular", "ui.tree", "ngMap", "app.ui.ctrls", "app.ui.directives", "app.ui.services", "app.controllers", "app.directives", "app.form.validation", "app.ui.form.ctrls", "app.ui.form.directives", "app.tables", "app.map", "app.task", "app.localization", "app.chart.ctrls", "app.chart.directives", "app.tekcapital.authModule"]).config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    return $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/dashboard.html"
    }).when("/dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/dashboard.html"
    }).when("/pages/features", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/features.html"
    }).when("/pages/login", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/login.html"
    }).when("/pages/login_fail", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/login_fail.html"
    }).when("/pages/create_idn_1", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/create_idn_1.html"
    }).when("/pages/create_idn_2", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/create_idn_2.html"
    }).when("/pages/create_idn_3", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/create_idn_3.html"
    }).when("/pages/create_idn_4", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/create_idn_4.html"
    }).when("/pages/create_idn_5", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/create_idn_5.html"
    }).when("/pages/create_idn_6", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/create_idn_6.html"
    }).when("/pages/create_idn_7", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/create_idn_7.html"
    }).when("/pages/signin", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/signin.html"
    }).when("/pages/signup", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/signup.html"
    }).when("/pages/lock-screen", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/lock-screen.html"
    }).when("/pages/profile", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/profile.html"
    }).when("/404", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/404.html"
    }).when("/pages/500", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/500.html"
    }).when("/pages/blank", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/blank.html"
    }).when("/pages/invoice", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/invoice.html"
    }).when("/pages/services", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/services.html"
    }).when("/pages/about", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/about.html"
    }).when("/pages/contact", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/pages/contact.html"
    }).when("/tasks", {
        templateUrl: "web-view/tasks/tasks.html"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/404"
    })
}]).run(function($rootScope,$location,UserService){
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event,next, current){
        if(UserService.isLogged == null || !UserService.isLogged){
            if(next.templateUrl === "web-view/pages/login.html"){
            }else{
                $location.path("/pages/login");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

}.call(this)

Below is my login page

```
    <div class="page page-general" ng-controller="AuthController">

<div class="signin-header">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <section class="logo">
            <span class="logo-icon "><img src="images/assets/logo_RS.png" width="262" height="48" alt="tekcapital" /></span>

            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="signup-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-container">

                 <section class="row signin-social text-center bg-info" style="padding: 12px 0">
                   Sign In To Tekcapital IDN

                </section>

                <span class="line-thru"></span>

                <form class="form-horizontal" name="loginForm" novalidate>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg" style="width:100%;">

                                <input type="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" ng-model="loginForm.userName" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg" style="width:100%;">

                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password"  ng-model="loginForm.password" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>{{loginForm.$valid}}</div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a href="#/pages/create_idn_1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg          btn-block" ng-click="getData()">Login</a>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my code for service and controller

```
function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app.tekcapital.authModule", []).factory("UserService", [function () {
        var sdo = {
            isLogged: false,
            username: ''
        };
        return sdo;
    }]).controller("AuthController", ["$scope", "$http", "UserService", function ($scope, $http, UserService) {
        $scope.validUser = "";
        $scope.loginForm = {};
        $scope.getData = function () {
            $http.post("http://localhost:8191/authenticate",{"userName":$scope.loginForm.userName,"password":$scope.loginForm.password})
                .success(function(dataFromServer, status, header, config){
                    console.log("data from server " + dataFromServer);
                    console.log("User Service " + UserService.isLogged)
                    if(dataFromServer == "true"){
                        UserService.isLogged = true;
                        UserService.username = "Test User Name";

                    }else{
                        UserService.isLogged = false;
                        UserService.username = "";
                    }
                    console.log("User Service 2 " + UserService.isLogged)
                });
        };
    }])
}.call(this);
```

Now the issue is that when I validate for the first time it stays on the login page. And on second successful attempt it redirects to another page. 
In case of wrong credentials it is working fine. It stays on login page. 
And even when I use $location.path('after/login/page') it moves me to that login page. 
But when I open a new tab with "localhost:8191/#/pages/success/ it again takes me to login page. 
If I have logged in once then it should not take me to login page. 
Need help in this regard.

Regards

Comment: Try setting some $location.url('somewhere/someplace') on login success?

Comment: Thanks. Yes adding $location.path works. But before going to that page of location.path it first goes to login page again and then redirects to the other page.